# How to update Cost for a stock item

Tags: acumatica

Is possible to call Update Cost process, in the stock item maintenance screen?  In my case, my custom code creates BOM records, then executes BOM cost roll.  Last step is to execute Update Cost, in order to push the pending cost data.  I notice the Update Cost process is actually a method in the base graph, not the stock item maintenance graph.  I am unsure how to execute the action button in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Update Cost action on Stock Items takes an additional parameter we need to figure out how to access an action with the following:

```
public PXAction<InventoryItem> action;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actions", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.ActionsFolder)]
protected virtual IEnumerable Action(PXAdapter adapter,
    [PXInt]
    [PXIntList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new string[] 
    { 
            "Update Price",
            "Update Cost",
            "View Restriction Group"                    

    })]
    int? actionID
    )
{
    // button action code here...
}
```

Looking at examples in Acumatica I was able to find out how to provide parameters to a PXAction that takes more than just the adapter. In our case we need to provide actionID a value.

To get this working we need to work with a new PXAdapter instance and pass this to the action. Here is a working sample:

```
var itemMaint = CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
var inventoryID = 151;
itemMaint.Item.Current = itemMaint.Item.Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID>(inventoryID);
// Must use this dummy view - actual view will not work
var view = PXView.Dummy.For<InventoryItem>(itemMaint);
var itemAdapter = new PXAdapter(view)
{
    Arguments = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "actionID", 2 } }
};
itemMaint.action.PressButton(itemAdapter);
```

Putting it all together which is what I used to test the example we end up with something like this...

1. Coll BOM Cost (cost roll)
2. Update pending cost (cost roll)
3. Update Cost (stock item)

Working Example:

```
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, () =>
{
    var costRoll = CreateInstance<BOMCostRoll>();
    costRoll.Settings.Current.SnglMlti = RollupSettings.SelectOptSM.Multi;
    costRoll.Settings.Current.BOMID = "00000000000041";
    costRoll.Settings.Current.RevisionID = "A";

    // ROLL COSTS
    costRoll.start.Press();

    var inventoryIds = new HashSet<int>();
    foreach (AMBomCost costRollRec in costRoll.BomCostRecs.Select())
    {
        inventoryIds.Add(costRollRec.InventoryID.GetValueOrDefault());
    }

    // UPDATE PENDING
    costRoll.updpnd.Press();

    var itemMaint = CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();

    foreach (var inventoryId in inventoryIds)
    {
        itemMaint.Clear();
        itemMaint.Item.Current = itemMaint.Item.Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID>(inventoryId);
        if (itemMaint.Item.Current == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Must use this dummy view - actual view will not work
        var view = PXView.Dummy.For<InventoryItem>(itemMaint);
        var itemAdapter = new PXAdapter(view)
        {
            Arguments = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"actionID", 2}}
        };
        // UPDATE COST
        itemMaint.action.PressButton(itemAdapter);
    }
});
```

Comment: I refer to the Update Cost action inside the stock item maintenance screen.  That action assigns the pending cost to effective cost field

Comment: sorry i was thinking just calling the update pending. I will try to review later and update